# How to remove a specific value in a JSON File in Python?

Tags: python, json

So I got a JSON File looking like

```
{
    "banned": [123, 456]
}
```

What I want to do is removing **only** the value 123 of banned if possible with Python's JSON Module or Python itself.

What I tried:

```
with open("banned.json", "w") as bannedload:
    bannedjson = json.load(bannedload)
    bannedjson["banned"].pop(123)
    # json.dump(bannedjson, bannedload) This Line was just for testing
```

Second try:

```
 with open("banned.json", "w") as bannedload:
    bannedjson = json.load(bannedload)
    del bannedjson["banned"][123]
    # json.dump(bannedjson, bannedload) This Line was just for testing
```

So does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @KlausD. I tried .pop and del (also with json.dump)

Comment: Show us your code!

Comment: Added the code @KlausD.

Comment: Both code blocks seem to be fine. Now you just have to re-open the file for writing (or use a new file) and `dump()` the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `del()` and `pop()` works based on index of the element, you can use `remove()` method to delete the element as:

```
bannedjson["banned"].remove(123)
```

Note that `remove()` throws error if the element to be deleted does not exist in the list. You can use the `in` clause to check before deleting:

```
elt = 123
if elt in bannedjson["banned"]: 
    bannedjson["banned"].remove(elt)
```

Further, `remove()` only removes the first occurrence of the element and you can use list comprehension to remove all elements as:

```
elt = 123
bannedjson["banned"] = [element for element in bannedjson["banned"] if elt != element]
```

Comment: So, I configured my version a bit and now it's working! Thanks for your help!